# Read Linux Shell Script

Tags: shell

how to read this?

```
if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
    print_package_file_error_and_exit "No package-file specified."
fi

readonly package_file="$1"
```

Comment: What do you mean? Are you asking what this script would do?

Comment: Is there something in particular that you are uncertain about? Does this code fragment cause issues?

Comment: `lt` stands for "less than". `$#` is the number of parameters passed to the script. `$1` is the first parameter.

Comment: @berndbausch please don't answer questions in comments.

Comment: @berndbausch If you want to be picky, the outcome of the `-lt` test depends on whether `$IFS` contains digits (since `$#` is unquoted).  We also don't know what `print_package_file_error_and_exit` does and if it really exits as the name implies.

Answer (score 2):

**First** we have a "if statement" in this form:

```
if COMMAND_1; then
    COMMAND_2
fi
```

Which tells the Shell if `COMMAND_1` executed successfully (returned 0), then execute `COMMAND_2`.

`COMMAND_1` in this example is `[ $# -lt 1 ]` which is a `test` command written using brackets and is equal to this: `test $# -lt 1`

`test $# -lt 1` returns 0 if `$#` (the number of parameters passed to this script) is less than (`-lt`) 1, causing to execute `COMMAND_2` which in this case is `print_package_file_error_and_exit "No package-file specified."`.

`print_package_file_error_and_exit` apparently is an application which should be installed on your system but it's more likely to be a shell function defined some where else in the script or in a sourced file (like your `bashrc`). By its name one could guess that it will print a message passed to it (in this case: `"No package-file specified."`) and then exit the script.

**Second** we have definition of a variable named `package_file` which is read-only (meaning that after you set its value you can not change it later) and set to the value of the first parameter passed to the script (`$1`).